# HTTP REFERER is blank for when user agent is switched to mobile devices in Firefox

Tags: php, user-agent

I'm trying to detect users who are coming from Facebook and perform a certain action specifically for those users.

For that, I have the following code:

```
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'facebook.com') !== false) 
    {
         // FB specific code
    }
```

This code is able to detect traffic that is coming from facebook *(and others who fake it, but that's not important for now)* for user agents that aren't mobile related, but `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` is `NULL` when the user agent is switched to say and iPhone or Android user agent.

I understand $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] should "*not be trusted*", but why would it work for one set of user agents and not the other?

Comment: User agents are under no obligation to send a referrer field, and if they do you can't expect it to be accurate.  You shouldn't rely on them doing so.

Comment: "when the user agent is switched". I would kind of expect that type of behavior if you're messing with non-standard features of a browser.

Comment: If your visitors are coming to your site via a Facebook app, edit your app's config to include a Facebook-specific URL parameter, ie. `http://yoursite.com/?fb=1`. Then you can check for the parameter to determine the source of the traffic.

Comment: Some browsers don't send a referrer if you're coming from a different domain. Referrer is not only unreliable, it's _super_ unreliable.

Comment: I'm switching user agents via a firefox addon. The code works for most desktop-based browsers, and fails for mobile-based browsers. I'd say that the "non-standard" feature is working fine and its a flaw in PHP's $_SERVER values.

Comment: It may work with mobile browsers and their quirks but not FF with a different user agent. It looks like there are 7 different implementations of the header parsing code. Which web server are you using? https://github.com/php/php-src/search?q=HTTP_REFERER&ref=cmdform